# Count transitions between different states in several time steps (columns)

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                   t1 = c("AV1", "AV1", "AZ", "AV1", "AV1","AV1","AV2"),
                   t2 = c("AV2", NA, "AV3", "AV2", "AV2",NA, "AV3"),
                   t3 = c("AZ", "AV2", "AV4", "AZ", "AZ","AV4","AV4"))
```

Each row represents an individual "id", with states (values) at several different time steps (columns "t1"-"t3"):

```
id t1  t2   t3
1 AV1  AV2  AZ
2 AV1  NA   AV2
3 AZ   AV3  AV4
4 AV1  AV2  AZ
5 AV1  AV2  AZ
6 AV1  NA   AV4
7 AV2  AV3  AV4
```

I want to count the different transitions, "from" a value in one time step, "to" a value in a subsequent time step, summarized for the entire data set:

```
 from            to                 count 
  AV1            AV2                 4             
  AV2            AZ                  3              
  AZ             AV3                 1             
  AV3            AV4                 2           
  AV1            AV4                 1
  AV2            AV3                 1
```

Thus, "count" represent the number of times a particular transition occurs. For example, AV1 to AV2 is occurs 4 times, AV2 to AZ 3 times. `NA`s are excluded.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid hard-coding of the columns, you may reshape your data to long format (`melt`). Use `head` and `tail`, withing each "id" (`by = id`), to align values in consecutive time steps. Count number of rows (`.N`) of each unique transition (`by = .(from, to)`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
d <- melt(data ,id.vars = "id", na.rm=TRUE)
d[ , .(from = head(value, -1), to = tail(value, -1)), by = id][ , .N, by = .(from, to)]
#   from  to N
# 1: AV1 AV2 4
# 2: AV2  AZ 3
# 3:  AZ AV3 1
# 4: AV3 AV4 2
# 5: AV1 AV4 1
# 6: AV2 AV3 1
```

---

A `base` alternative in a similar vein, albeit with the transitions concatenated:

```
d <- na.omit(reshape(data, varying = list(2:4), direction = "long"))
as.data.frame(table(unlist(by(d, d$id, function(dat) paste(head(dat$t1, -1), tail(dat$t1, -1), sep = " - ")))))

#        Var1 Freq
# 1 AV1 - AV2    4
# 2 AV1 - AV4    1
# 3 AV2 - AV3    1
# 4  AV2 - AZ    3
# 5 AV3 - AV4    2
# 6  AZ - AV3    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic method that will work for an arbitrary number of columns. We find all the pair combinations of the columns (index-wise). We use them to index the columns from the original df, and put them in list. Pasting the elements, doing some cleaning (`trimws(gsub('NA', '', do.call(paste, a[i1[,x]]))`) and then using `table` function, we get your expected results. Wrapping it in `as.data.frame` gives your expected output structure.

```
i1 <- combn(seq_along(a[-1])+1, 2)

final_d <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(lapply(seq(ncol(i1)), function(x) {
               v1 <- trimws(gsub('NA', '', do.call(paste, a[i1[,x]]))); 
               grep('\\s', v1, value = TRUE)
               }))))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      Var1 Freq
> 1 AV1 AV2    4
> 2 AV1 AV4    1
> 3  AV1 AZ    3
> 4 AV2 AV3    1
> 5 AV2 AV4    1
> 6  AV2 AZ    3
> 7 AV3 AV4    2
> 8  AZ AV3    1
> 9  AZ AV4    1
> ```

Or to get it exactly the same,

```
setNames(data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(final_d$Var1),' ',fixed=TRUE)), 
                    final_d$Freq), 
                    c('from', 'to', 'freq.'))
```

> ```
>   from  to freq.
> 1  AV1 AV2     4
> 2  AV1 AV4     1
> 3  AV1  AZ     3
> 4  AV2 AV3     1
> 5  AV2 AV4     1
> 6  AV2  AZ     3
> 7  AV3 AV4     2
> 8   AZ AV3     1
> 9   AZ AV4     1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach could be

```
library(dplyr)

d1 <- data %>% group_by(t1, t2) %>% filter(!is.na(t1) & !is.na(t2)) %>% summarise(n()) %>% `colnames<-`(c("from", "to", "weight")) %>% as.data.frame()
d2 <- data %>% group_by(t2, t3) %>% filter(!is.na(t2) & !is.na(t3)) %>% summarise(n()) %>% `colnames<-`(c("from", "to", "weight")) %>% as.data.frame()
d3 <- data %>% group_by(t1, t3) %>% filter(!is.na(t1) & !is.na(t3)) %>% summarise(n()) %>% `colnames<-`(c("from", "to", "weight")) %>% as.data.frame()
#final data
df <- rbind(d1, d2, d3) %>% group_by(from, to) %>% summarise(weight=sum(weight)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Hi @Prem , thanks for your reply. However, I noticed that there are more relations in the results, for instance, AV1>AZ and AV2>AV4 which doesn't exist directly but indirectly.

Comment: @MohammadZahrawy `df` has all the relations which you are expecting. BTW Sotos' answer is great and can be replicated on any numbers of columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
A `tidyverse` approach which avoids hard coding columns could follow a similar approach to @Henrik's excellent accepted answer.  In this case, I've used the `lead` function to combine adjacent values before taking a `count` of the result.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  transmute(from = value, to = lead(value)) %>% filter(!is.na(to)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  count(from, to)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>    from    to     n
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1   AV1   AV2     4
#> 2   AV1   AV4     1
#> 3   AV2   AV3     1
#> 4   AV2    AZ     3
#> 5   AV3   AV4     2
#> 6    AZ   AV3     1
```

**Original solution**
How about something like this? It's not very elegant but I think it will get the job done.

```r
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(id = 1:7,
               t1 = c("AV1", "AV1", "AZ", "AV1", "AV1", "AV1", "AV2"),
               t2 = c("AV2", NA, "AV3", "AV2", "AV2", NA, "AV3"),
               t3 = c("AZ", "AV2", "AV4", "AZ", "AZ", "AV4", "AV4"))


cnt1 <- data %>% filter(!is.na(t2)) %>% count(t1, t2) %>% rename(from = t1, to = t2)
cnt2 <- data %>% filter(!is.na(t2)) %>% count(t2, t3) %>% rename(from = t2, to = t3)
cnt3 <- data %>% filter(is.na(t2)) %>% count(t1, t3) %>% rename(from = t1, to = t3)

cnt1 %>%
  bind_rows(cnt2) %>%
  bind_rows(cnt3) %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarise(weight = sum(n))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   from [?]
#>    from    to weight
#>   <chr> <chr>  <int>
#> 1   AV1   AV2      4
#> 2   AV1   AV4      1
#> 3   AV2   AV3      1
#> 4   AV2    AZ      3
#> 5   AV3   AV4      2
#> 6    AZ   AV3      1
```

Comment: Thank you. it works, but this is a sample, i have 53 sequences (53 columns) haha. is there anyway to make that possible with your code?

Comment: I thought that might be the case @MohammadZahrawy! There must be a better way to do this. Hopefully someone else can provide a better solution!

Comment: @MohammadZahrawy, I've added an edit to include a `tidyverse` option which should work for any number of columns.